# Does OleDbTransaction.Commit() closes the connection?

Tags: vb.net, transactions, database-connection, commit

I need to run a number of queries as part of a transaction.

There's a method in my project, creatively named `RunQuery()`, that concentrates the database queries, so I'll be using it. It has four parameters:

- a string indicating which database to run the query on,
- a string containing the query,
- a table name for when the result needs to be a data set,
- an `Enum` that indicates what kind of query/results is wanted: Select query returning a data reader, Select query returning a data set, Insert/Update/Delete query.

(If you need more detail, I'll supply it gladly. I'll keep this short-ish for now.)

The point is that when you want to run a query, you don't have to worry about the connection or command objects, you just write your query and call `RunQuery()`. Fine.

Now, I've added a new `ByRef` parameter to `RunQuery()`, an `IDbTransaction` to track the transaction. It needs to be handled at least partially outside `RunQuery()`, if only to commit after the very last call, but on the first call it's set at `Nothing`.

I've also added an item to the `Enum` so `RunQuery()` knows it has to deal with a transaction.

My code looks like this:

```
    Dim z_lisQuery As New List(Of String)
    ' [...] Filling z_lisQuery with queries

    Dim z_dtrTransaction As IDbTransaction = Nothing

    Dim z_blnExecutionOk As Boolean = True

    For Each z_strQuery As String In z_lisQuery
        z_blnExecutionOk = z_blnExecutionOk And RunQuery(p_strDbId,
                                                         z_strQuery,
                                                         "",
                                                         z_dtrTransaction,
                                                         QueryAction.ExecutionTransaction)
        If Not z_blnExecutionOk Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If z_blnExecutionOk Then
        z_dtrTransaction.Commit()
    End If

    z_dtrTransaction?.Connection.Dispose()
    z_dtrTransaction?.Dispose()
```

(A `Rollback()` is executed within `RunQuery()` if something goes wrong.)

When I run that and no errors happen, everything goes fine until the penultimate line:

`z_dtrTransaction?.Connection.Dispose()` throws an exception because `z_dtrTransaction.Connection` is `Nothing`.

The obvious workaround is to use `z_dtrTransaction?.Connection?.Dispose()`, so that's not what I'm puzzled about.

What I'm puzzled about is that `z_dtrTransaction.Connection` is still a functional `OleDbConnection` object when execution reaches `z_dtrTransaction.Commit()`. But after `z_dtrTransaction.Commit()` is executed, `z_dtrTransaction.Connection` is `Nothing`.

I can see the point of that, but the language reference doesn't seem to indicate that it should happen that way and I haven't found a reference to that way of doing things.

Is it officially stated somewhere that this behavior is the normal one? Or is it just with `OleDbConnection` and not with `SqlConnection`, for instance?

(Even if it is, obviously I'm keeping `z_dtrTransaction?.Connection?.Dispose()` because I'm not entirely sure what happens in case of a rollback.)

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for of course, but by implementing you connections (Any class that implements IDisposable for that matter) withing a "Using" block, it takes care of the cleanup for you

Comment: Yup, quite right. As you noted, it can't be used here since the connection has to be kept alive through all the calls of `RunQuery()`, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes no sense.  If you need to keep it alive, why are you going anywhere near disposing it?  Even so, IDisposable objects are generally supposed to be short term.  Create, use and destroy, you're probably making complications for yourself by recycling them

Comment: I'll try to put it more clearly : the connection has to be kept alive through all the calls of `RunQuery()` in a single transaction. Then (and only then) it needs to be disposed of. Since the scope of operation is that of a transaction, I feel it still is short-term. Does it make more sense put that way?